# Accessing the elements of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I have a task to create a program to read from a file and check which employees have worked together for longer. I have already created the code to read from a file and store the data in an array. You can check it below:

```
string path;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter the path of the file: ");
    path = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The path is not correct.");
    }

} while (!File.Exists(path));

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (string line in lines) //just to check if the program can read from a file
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.WriteLine();



for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] values = lines[i].ToString().Split(',');

    foreach (string el in values) //just to check if the value are stored inside the array
    {
        Console.Write(el + " ");
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This code gives this result:

```
Please enter the path of the file: C:\Users\...
143, 12, 2013-11-01, 2014-01-05
145, 10, 2009/01/01, 2011/04/27
140, 10, 2009.03.01, 2011.04.27
111, 10, 2009.03.01, NULL

143  12  2013-11-01  2014-01-05  
145  10  2009/01/01  2011/04/27  
140  10  2009.03.01  2011.04.27  
111  10  2009.03.01  NULL
```

(the columns represent: employerID, projectID, DateFrom and DateTo respectively). Now I need to create a code that calculates the time that 2 employees have worked on the same project (using project id and the dates to calculate the period of work together). I need some help to understand how I can do that. Thank you!

Comment: Please paste the text instead of the picture.

Comment: What's the 5th value?

Comment: Can `DateTime.Subtract()` help?

Comment: @tymtam the 5th value isn't important, it's just Console.WriteLine(values.Length);

Comment: @tymtam that's the result of the code. It prints what's inside the .txt file I'm providing by entering the path

Comment: Yes, it's the result, but it's text, you should still be able to select, copy and then paste it here.

Comment: You probably won't be able to achieve what you want in that way. You need actual variables, not string representations. You may create classes, parse the values to be able to use them later. You can store collection of projects on each employee. Then you will probably need loop in a loop to iterate trough all entries and do a check with all entries. You may also want to try LINQ instead.

Comment: @MikeSar can you please write some steps I could follow like the answer below?

Comment: @Ada 1. Decide if you want to work with employees and their projects(2 classes) or employee project entries(1 class, like suggested in the answer below). 2. Design classes: Project(id, date from and date to) and Emploee (id, projects - List<Project>) OR some EmployeeProjectEntry with 4 fields you need. Use for example int.Parse() to extract values. 3. Create objects with your data. 4. Design you program logic. Divide and conquer. Think of your input and output and how to get from A to B. If the problem is too complex, try to split it into smaller problems and repeat. 5. Implement and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good start:

1. Create a class EmployeeWorkPeriod with the 4 fields
2. Parse `values` into data types like `int` and `DateTime` (and `DateTime?`).

Once you have these object you can start writing you program logic.